# Place pages in a store (Economy system) discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Sorry if this code can be a little disastrous but it is what I have at the moment (I'm a little newbie in this kind of things and I came here to learn more), I'm trying to add pages to the store where only on each page can be seen 5 items (something similar to unbelievaboat), these pages will be enlarged by adding more items, this is the code that I have at the moment:

```py
  @commands.command(aliases=['mall', 'store'])
  async def shop(self, ctx, cur_page=1):
    with open('json/servers/{guild}/Shop.json'.format(guild=ctx.guild.id)) as f:
      shop = json.load(f)
    
    with open('json/servers/{guild}/{guild}-Server.json'.format(guild=ctx.guild.id)) as f:
      data = json.load(f)

      currency = data["currency"]
  
    
    codename = shop.keys()
    codename = list(codename)[0:5]
    codenamelen = len(shop.keys())
    pagelen = -(-len(shop.keys())//3)
    for codename2 in codename:
      efectivo = shop[codename2]["PRICE"]
      price = re.sub(r"(?<!^)(?=(\d{3})+$)", r",", efectivo)
    if codenamelen > 5:
      codename = shop.keys()
      codename = list(codename)[0:5]
      text = ''.join(f'{"" if shop[codename]["EMOJI"] == "None" else shop[codename]["EMOJI"]} **{shop[codename]["NAME"]}** `ID: {codename}` ─ __{price}__ {currency}\n{shop[codename]["DESCRIPTION"]}\n\n' for codename in codename)
      embed = discord.Embed(description=f'¡Bienvenido a la tienda!\nUsa **`{ctx.prefix}buy <item>`** para comprar y **`{ctx.prefix}iteminfo <item>`** para mas información.\n\n{text}', color=0x007fff)
      embed.set_author(name="Tienda de {guild}".format(guild=ctx.guild.name), icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
      embed.set_footer(text=f"Paginas: {cur_page}/{int(pagelen)}")
      msg = await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)

      await msg.add_reaction("⬅️")
      await msg.add_reaction("⏸️")
      await msg.add_reaction("➡️")

      def check(reaction, user):
        if not user.bot and user == ctx.message.author:
          return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '⬅️', '⏸️', '➡️'

      while True:
          try: 
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=300, check=check)
          except asyncio.TimeoutError:
              await msg.clear_reactions()
              break
          #print(reaction)
          #print(user)
          try:
            if reaction.emoji == '➡️' and user == ctx.message.author and cur_page != pagelen:
              cur_page += 1
              codename = shop.keys()
              codename = list(codename)[5:]
              text = ''.join(f'{"" if shop[codename]["EMOJI"] == "None" else shop[codename]["EMOJI"]} **{shop[codename]["NAME"]}** `ID: {codename}` ─ __{price}__ {currency}\n{shop[codename]["DESCRIPTION"]}\n\n' for codename in codename)
              await msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
              embed = discord.Embed(description=f'¡Bienvenido a la tienda!\nUsa **`{ctx.prefix}buy <item>`** para comprar\n**`{ctx.prefix}iteminfo <item>`** para mas información.\n\n{text}', color=0x007fff)
              embed.set_author(name="Tienda de {guild}".format(guild=ctx.guild.name), icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
              embed.set_footer(text=f"Paginas: {cur_page}/{pagelen}")
              embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
              await msg.edit(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
            elif reaction.emoji == '⏸️' and user == ctx.message.author:
              await msg.clear_reactions()
              break
            elif reaction.emoji == '⬅️' and user == ctx.message.author and cur_page > 0:
              cur_page -= 1
              codename = shop.keys()
              codename = list(codename)[0:5]
              text = ''.join(f'{"" if shop[codename]["EMOJI"] == "None" else shop[codename]["EMOJI"]} **{shop[codename]["NAME"]}** `ID: {codename}` ─ __{price}__ {currency}\n{shop[codename]["DESCRIPTION"]}\n\n' for codename in codename)
              await msg.remove_reaction(reaction, user)
              embed = discord.Embed(description=f'¡Bienvenido a la tienda!\nUsa **`{ctx.prefix}buy <item>`** para comprar\n**`{ctx.prefix}iteminfo <item>`** para mas información.\n\n{text}', color=0x007fff)
              embed.set_author(name="Tienda de {guild}".format(guild=ctx.guild.name), icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
              embed.set_thumbnail(url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
              embed.set_footer(text=f"Paginas: {cur_page}/{pagelen}")
              await msg.edit(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
          except:
            pass
    else:
      text = ''.join(f'{"" if shop[codename]["EMOJI"] == "None" else shop[codename]["EMOJI"]} **{shop[codename]["NAME"]}** `ID: {codename[:5]}` ─ __{price}__ {currency}\n{shop[codename]["DESCRIPTION"]}\n\n' for codename in shop)
      embed = discord.Embed(description=f'¡Bienvenido a la tienda!\nUsa **`{ctx.prefix}buy <item>`** para comprar\n**`{ctx.prefix}iteminfo <item>`** para mas información.\n\n{text}', color=0x007fff)
      embed.set_author(name="Tienda de {guild}".format(guild=ctx.guild.name), icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
      msg = await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the existing [`Menus` extension](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus) which does all of this stuff for you already. The [Pagination example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord-ext-menus#pagination) is a very easy-to-understand example of what you're trying to accomplish. Making this yourself is a bit of a hassle, as you're discovering, so I really wouldn't do it.

Comment: Mmh ok, I will try it with that extension. Thanks for replying!